# How do I create multiple stores?

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps

Below I have posted some code that was edited from an article. I can only show one store location on the map. However, I would like to have multiple location that are present.

Here is the code:

```
    <div id="manualEntry">
    Your current location
    <input id="manualAddress" type="text" style="width: 500px" />
    <input id="getManualDirections" type="button" value="Get Directions" />
</div>
<div id="mapContainer" style="height: 500px">
    <div style="float: left">
        <div id="directionsMap" style="float: none; position: relative; width: 720px; height: 400px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="directionsList" style="float: left; overflow: auto; width: 250px; height: 400px">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var map = null;
        var directionsManager = null;
        var location = null;
        var STORE_LOCATION = "San Jose, CA";


        showManualEntry();

        $("#askPermission").hide();
        loadMap();
        // Get the location
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 2000
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError, options);

        function loadMap() {
            // Initialize the map
            if (!map) {
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("directionsMap"),
                         { credentials: "YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY" });
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            map.entities.clear();
            if (position) {
                location = position.coords;
                map.setView({ zoom: 15, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(location.lattitude, location.longitude) })
            }
            if (!directionsManager) {
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', { callback: createDirectionsManager });
            }
            else {
                createDirectionsManager();
            }
        }

        function createDirectionsManager() {
            var displayMessage;
            if (!directionsManager) {
                directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
                displayMessage = 'Directions Module loaded\n';
                displayMessage += 'Directions Manager loaded';
            }
            directionsManager.resetDirections();
            directionsErrorEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', directionsError);
            directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', directionsUpdated);
            createDrivingRoute(location);
        }

        function directionsUpdated() {
            // Show Success message if required
        }
        function directionsError(args) {
            // Show Error message if required
        }

        function createDrivingRoute(coords) {
            if (!directionsManager) { createDirectionsManager(); }
            directionsManager.resetDirections();
            // Set Route Mode to driving 
            directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });
            var fromWayPoint = null;
            if (coords != null) {
                fromWayPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(
                                {
                                    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(coords.latitude, coords.longitude)
                                });
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(fromWayPoint);
            }
            else {
                fromWayPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: $("#manualAddress").val() });
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(fromWayPoint);
            }
            var toWayPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: STORE_LOCATION });
            directionsManager.addWaypoint(toWayPoint);
            // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
            directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsList') });
            directionsManager.calculateDirections();
        }


        function showManualEntry() {
            $("#manualEntry").show();
        }

        $("#getManualDirections").click(function () {
            loadMap();
            showPosition(null);
        });

        function positionError(position) {
            switch (position.code) {
                case 1:
                    showManualEntry();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    showManualEntry();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    showManualEntry();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```

Here is the article:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=783

Comment: I was just checking your code and the article, and i think that there is just one storeLocation here. The other location is the user's location if detected by the location service. You will never get multiple locations this way.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicolas pointed out the code you have will only show one location on the map. What you first need is a data set of your stores. Many Bing Maps customers use the Bing Spatial Data Services to store their store data and have it exposed as a spatial REST service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585132.aspx Once you have a data source file that matches the required schema you can upload it to your account using the Bing Maps portal as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh698204.aspx

Once you have a data source you can then easily query the data source and have it display your nearby store locations. Here are some examples:

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#SpatialDataServices1
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/dynamically-updating-data-in-bing-maps-v7/

If you have your data in a database you may prefer to expose this data using a custom web service. If this is the case then take a look at these blog posts:

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/07/31/how-to-create-a-spatial-web-service-that-connects-a-database-to-bing-maps-using-ef5/
http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/08/05/advance-spatial-queries-using-entity-framework-5/